# Enum Extension Method – ToDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have tried to add an extension method to an enum which converts it to a DataTable so that it can be bound to a DropDownList which works fine.

```
public enum Response
{
    Yes = 1,
    No = 2,
    Maybe = 3
}
```

public static DataTable ToDataSource(this Enum e)
{
    Type type = e.GetType(); 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("text", typeof(String));

```
foreach (Int32 value in Enum.GetValues(type))
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { value, Enum.GetName(type, value) });
}

return dt;
```

}

However is there a way that I can use the extension method on the enum itself (Response.ToDataSource) rather than having to use it hanging of a value Responce.Yes.ToDataSource?

I have tried creating an new instance (Response new response, response.ToDataSource but I get a build error saying that “it may not be initialised before accessing”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot.  Extension methods are a feature which allows you to have the appearance of calling a new method on an instance of a type.  It has no capacity to give this capability to types themselves.

When I want to add a set of methods add type level I usually create a new static class called OriginalTypeNameUtil and add the methods there.  For example ResponseUtil.  This way the class name is visible when I type the original type name.

Comment: The reason for the extension method is that I want to apply it to all enums and don’t want to create lots of helper classes. I know I could create an EnumHelper class with the method there but was trying to group it with all my other enum extensions methods I have written.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar only, instead of extending the Enum type, I extended the DataTable .

```
public static DataTable FromEnum(this DataTable dt, Type enumType) {
if (!enumType.IsEnum) { throw new ArgumentException("The specified type is not a System.Enum."); }
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
Array values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
List<string> enumItemNames = new List<string>();
List<int> enumItemValues = new List<int>();
try {
    // build the table
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(string)));
    // Get the enum item names (using the enum item's description value if defined)
    foreach (string enumItemName in names) {
        enumItemNames.Add(((Enum)Enum.Parse(enumType, enumItemName)).ToDescription());
    }
    // Get the enum item values
    foreach (object itemValue in values) {
        enumItemValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(enumType, itemValue.ToString())));
    }
    // Make sure that the data table is empty
    tbl.Clear();

    // Fill the data table
    for (int i = 0; i <= names.Length - 1; i++) {
        DataRow newRow = tbl.NewRow();
        newRow["Value"] = enumItemValues[i];
        newRow["Text"] = enumItemNames[i];
        tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
}
catch {
    tbl.Clear();
    tbl = dt;
}
// Return the data table to the caller
return tbl;
```

}

and it's called like this:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable().FromEnum(typeof(YourEnum));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want a real static method and an "enum-like" class:

```
public class Response
{
    public static readonly Response Yes = new Response(1);
    public static readonly Response No = new Response(2);
    public static readonly Response Maybe = new Response(3);

    int value;

    private Response(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static DataTable ToDataSource()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for the quick responses but unfortunately I have to use enums as they are used throughout the application and deviating away from this standard just to get some desired functionality would not be approved.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a struct that emulates an enum:

```
   public struct Response
   {
     private int ival;
     private Response() {} // private ctor to eliminate instantiation
     private Response(int val) { ival = val; }
     private static readonly Response Yes = new Response(1);
     private static readonly Response No = new Response(2);
     private static readonly Response Maybe= new Response(3);
     // etc...  ...for whatever other functionality you want.... 
   }
```

Then this struct functions exactly (close to exactly !) like an enum, and you can add extensiuon methods to it...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create an extension method on an enum.

You could however create a generic function that accept enums and create a table from it.

```
public static DataTable CreateDataSource<TEnum>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(TEnum);

    if (enumType.IsEnum) // It is not possible to do "where TEnum : Enum"
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Value", enumType);

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            table.Rows.Add(Enum.GetName(enumType, value), value);
        }

        return table;
    }
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Type TEnum is not an enumeration.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if you choose to go the route of implementing a 'Enum-Class' and find yourself in a position where the constructor isnt allowed to be private, you'll need to override Equals and GetHashCode.

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Test));

Array test = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test));
var vals = test.Cast<int>();

var source = from n in names
             from v in vals
             select new
             {
                 Text = n,
                 Value = v
             };
```

Not tested but was quick :)

Comment: How does this relate to his question?

Comment: That'll teach me to read all of the question! :) First reply on stackoverflow too! oops :P